# Python Requests: Passing Auth token

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm using MailJet's SMS API and I'm having trouble getting the token/authentification syntax right.

In cURL, the request should look like (cf [Docs](https://dev.mailjet.com/reference/sms/send-message/)):

```
curl -s \
     -X POST \
     --user "$MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC:$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE" \
     https://api.mailjet.com/v4/sms-send \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{
        "From": "MJPilot",
        "To": "+33600000000",
        "Text": "Have a nice SMS flight with Mailjet!"
      }'
```

But I don't know how to convert this phrasing to Python, this is my current idea:

```
import requests, json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'MYTOKEN',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
tel='XXXX'
message = "this is a message"
payload= {"From":"Me", "To":tel, "message":message}
r_sms = requests.post("https://api.mailjet.com/v4/sms-send", data=payload, headers=headers)
print("SMS SENT" + str(r_sms.json()))
```

with the following response:

```
SMS SENT{'ErrorIdentifier': 'f403ce05-1db3-4c30-ac74-314fa93a9e84', 'ErrorCode': 'mj-0002', 'ErrorMessage': 'Malformed JSON, please review the syntax and properties types.', 'StatusCode': 400}
```

I know my token is valid because I can run the request correctly via Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payload is `json`, so the kwarg is `json`, not `data`:

```
r_sms = requests.post("https://api.mailjet.com/v4/sms-send", json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Also, in your payload, it looks like it should be `"Text"` not `"message"`